# How to add a day to using php strftime

Tags: php, datetime, time

If i am formatting a date like this and want to add a day is there a way to do this using strftime?

```
_%Y%m%d
```

so i can do this:

```
20120704
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 86,400 seconds to the timestamp (second parameter)?  E.g. `strftime('%Y%m%d', time() + 86400)`

Comment: No not yet how can i do that?

Comment: 86400 seconds isn't necessarily "a day". Most common examples are the days when daylight savings time changes -- these days have 23 hours or 25 hours. Recently, a leap second occurred, which made the day last 86401 seconds. Using 86400 seconds is a decent approximation, though :-)

Comment: @ChristianStieber, the only problem is that decent approximations don't always work. If it's not exact, there's room for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [strtotime()](http://us.php.net/strtotime).  Something like this:

```
$date = date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class for dates.

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-07-03');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('Ymd') . "\n"; // Will echo 20120704
```